# Configuring TypeRepresentationStrategy for EmbeddedGraphDatabase

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I cannot configure `TypeRepresentationStrategy` because of the following reason:

> Failed to convert value of type 'org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase' to required type 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.GraphDatabase';

I use Spring-Data-Neo4j 3.1.4 and Neo4j 2.1.2.

This is because the `graphDatabaseService` instance I define in my spring-context configuration is type of `EmbeddedGraphDatabase`, see my configuration:

```
<util:map id="config">
    <entry key="remote_shell_enabled" value="true"/>
    <entry key="cache-type" value="weak"/>
</util:map>

<bean id="graphDbFactory" class="org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory"/>

<bean id="graphDbBuilder" factory-bean="graphDbFactory" factory-method="newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder">
    <constructor-arg value="target/neo4j-db-plain"/>
</bean>

<bean id="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-bean="graphDbBuilder" factory-method="setConfig">
    <constructor-arg ref="config"/>
</bean>

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-method="newGraphDatabase"
      destroy-method="shutdown"/>

<bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper" init-method="start"
      destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService"/>
</bean>

<neo4j:config base-package="com.hobbydeed.graph.model" graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />

<bean id="typeRepresentationStrategyFactory" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="graphDatabaseService"/>
    <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.Strategy">
        <value>Indexed</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The question is how can I configure `TypeRepresentation` to "Indexed" when `org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase` `implements` `org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService`, but `TypeRepresentationFactory` wants `org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.GraphDatabase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `nodeTypeRepresentationStrategy` bean that you can override with your chosen strategy.

For the strategy factory as you've used you can just use the "graphDatabase" bean reference.

Or you use `DelegatingGraphDatabase(graphDatabaseService)` as a bean for `graphDatabase` which is the default.